# Is low power mode in iOS good for battery?

Tags: iphone

Is always keeping 'low powered mode' on iPhone SE, running iOS 10.2.1 , good for battery health?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean by 'health.' If you mean time before you need to recharge, then yes - by reducing the background services, the battery will last longer until you need to recharge it. If you are really strapped for energy, turning on airplane mode or just shutting the phone off entirely until you absolutely need to use it.

However, if by 'health', you mean the number of charge cycles the battery will last, that should remain unaffected.

Comment: Surely if you use less power, you're going to go through fewer charge cycles? If so, the answer is "yes". However, I would expect ambient temperatures and general aging of the battery chemistry to have any impact long before the small difference made by turning on battery saver mode.
Plus not using features to improve the health of a phone you're probably going to replace in 2 years is a false economy in my view, since you've paid a premium for all of these features in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> Low Power Mode reduces the amount of power that your iPhone uses when the battery gets low.
>
> When Low Power Mode is on, your iPhone will last longer before you need to charge it, but some features might take longer to update or complete.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT205234

Comment: Sorry - this does not address the question about battery health.

Comment: Low Power mode won't effect battery health, it will just reduce the speed at which the battery deplets due to a range of background processes being suspended whilst the mode is active. 

Battery Health is mainly determined by the external temperatures that the phone is operating in, and when you decide to charge the phone. Mid Cycle charges are generally not good for battery health.

Answer (score 0):

It does not affect the battery health. According to [apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205234), low power mode simply **removes** some unnecessary features for a longer battery life.